# Django custom SQL Query not working with params

Tags: python, django, sqlite, django-models

I'm using **SQLite**

This is my query. I want to retrieve three columns and order by one of those column name.

```
query = "SELECT user_name, %s, %s FROM highscores_skills ORDER BY %s DESC"
cursor.execute(query, [skill, skill_exp, skill_exp])
```

I'm getting `skill` from a GET request and `skill_exp` is basically '_exp' append to skill.

Unfortunately this isn't working.
I'm getting column names as result.
Like this,
John, attack, attack_exp
Doe, attack, attack_exp

where attack is value of `skill` and attack_exp is value of `skill_exp`

It works if I don't use params but that's prone to SQL Injection.

I'm not sure what's wrong. I've also tried using `?` instead of `%s` as placeholder like how it is in Python SQLite but nothing.

Comment: you cannot use placeholders as column names(only as comparison values) so getting it from user input probably isnt a great idea... that said you can always do normal python string formatting ... furthermore why arent you just using the django ORM?

Comment: @JoranBeasley Ah, bummer.
I'm not exactly getting it as user input. I'm using query string to pass info.
I'll retrieve value in urls.py I guess.

Thanks.

Comment: @JoranBeasley I can use python string formatting but SQL injection. and I don't want to use django ORM because I want the result in a list and not in model.

Comment: so convert the models to a list of tuples instead ... the overhead is almost none ... and its a much better thing to do ...

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use placeholders for column names in sql engines

A.

```
query = "SELECT user_name, %s, %s FROM highscores_skills ORDER BY %s DESC"%(skill, skill_exp, skill_exp)
cursor.execute(query)
```

insecure because of sqlinjection

B.

```
 allowed_query_verbs = ["attack","defend","armor","magic"]
 queries = dict(
    "SELECT user_name, {0}, {0}_exp FROM highscores_skills ORDER BY {0}_exp DESC".format(v) for v in allowed_query_verbs
 )
 cursor.execute(queries[skill])
```

much safer since only allows predefined queries

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting value from url now instead of query string. Which seems safe enough.
Thanks though.